# rotate a 4x4 array by 180 degrees c#

Tags: c#, arrays, matrix, rotation

hi i need to know how to rotate an array by 180 degrees in place. currently i can get it to rotate 90 degrees but just cannot get it to rotate any further. If anyone can help me that would be great as I've been stuck on this question for a couple of days now. Thanks, here is my code:

```
namespace Question_2_1_
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[,] array = new int[4, 4] {
                { 1,2,3,4 },
                { 5,6,7,8 },
                { 9,0,1,2 },
                { 3,4,5,6 } };

            int[,] rotated = RotateMatrix(array, 4);    
            var rowCount = array.GetLength(0);
            var colCount = array.GetLength(1);

            for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < colCount; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(String.Format("{0}", rotated[i, j]));
                }

                Console.Write(Environment.NewLine);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static int[,] RotateMatrix(int[,] matrix, int n) 
        {
            int[,] ret = new int[n, n];

            for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) 
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) 
                {
                    ret[i, j] = matrix[n - j - 1, i];
                }                   
            }

            return ret;                     
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Before typing code for problems like this, I like to visualize it (with, for instance, pen & paper). Once you know where each entry ends up, it's easy to type the code.

Comment: if you know for sure rotating 90 degrees works.....do it twice.

Comment: Can you add the expected result in the bottom of your code (as comments)? I want to be clear on what you mean by rotation.

Answer (score 0):

You say you want to rotate in-place, but your rotate method returns a new array. Rotating in-place means you modify the matrix itself, without creating a new one.
But, if you're rotating 90 degrees, you can of course only rotate in-place if the matrix is square.
However, you can always rotate in-place if you're rotating 180 degrees. Let's take a non-square matrix:
`{ a, b, c, d, e, f },
{ g, h ,i, j, k, l },
{ m, n, o, p, q, r }`
If we rotate it 180 degrees, we end up with:
`{ r, q, p, o, n, m },
{ l, k, j, i, h, g },
{ f, e, d, c, b, a }`
You can see that an item at [r, c] ends up at [#rows - r - 1, #columns - c - 1]. (0-based of course),
so b at [0, 1] ends up at [3 - 0 - 1, 6 - 1 - 1]

The method you can use is: first swap a and r, then b and q, etc.
This is similar to reversing a 1-dimensional array, just in 2 dimensions.
Just as when reversing a 1-dimensional array, we only go halfway:
the last 2 items we swap are i and j.
I made the method generic, so you can rotate any matrix with it.

```
static void Rotate180<T>(T[,] matrix) {
    int rowCount = matrix.GetLength(0), columnCount = matrix.GetLength(1);
    int max = rowCount * columnCount / 2, m = 0;
    for (int r = 0; ; ++r) {
        for (int c = 0; c < columnCount; ++c) {
            Swap(matrix, r, c, rowCount - r - 1, columnCount - c - 1);
            if (++m >= max) return;
        }
    }
}

static void Swap<T>(T[,] matrix, int r1, int c1, int r2, int c2) {
    T temp = matrix[r1, c1];
    matrix[r1, c1] = matrix[r2, c2];
    matrix[r2, c2] = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer you're looking for is:

```
ret[i, j] = [n - (i + 1), n - j - 1];
```

However, this is not in-place as you're creating an entirely different array "ret"

Answer (score 0):

Do it with reversing the columns first, and then the rows.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var A = new int[,] { { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, { 5, 6, 7, 8 }, { 9, 10, 11, 12 }, { 13, 14, 15, 16 } };
        RotateMatrix180(ref A);
        // A = {{16,15,14,.. }, .. , { ..3,2,1} }
    }

    public static void RotateMatrix180<T>(ref T[,] matrix)
    {
        int n = matrix.GetLength(0), m = matrix.GetLength(1);
        if(n!=m) { /* error  */ }

        for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j<n/2; j++)
            {
                T temp = matrix[i, j];
                matrix[i, j]=matrix[i,n-j-1];
                matrix[i, n-j-1]=temp;
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i<n/2; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j<n; j++)
            {
                T temp = matrix[i, j];
                matrix[i, j]=matrix[n-i-1, j];
                matrix[n-i-1, j]=temp;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

PS. I added the `ref` keyword to make it obvious the function modifies the existing array. The code will work the same without it, because arrays are always reference types.